# How to match a substring following after a string satisfying the specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

Imagine, that I have the string `12.34some_text`.

How can I match the substring following after the second character (`4` in my case) after the `.` character. In that particular case the string I want to match is `some_text`.

For the string `56.78another_text` it will be `another_text` and so on.

All accepted strings have the pattern `\d\d\.\d\d\w*`

Comment: What language are you using? Generally, you can use `\..{2}(.*)` and grab the Group 1 text. https://regex101.com/r/eH7wJ0/1

Comment: Is your question "how to only match text in a string"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to match everything from the second character after a specific one (i.e. the dot) you can use a lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<=[.]\d{2})(\w*)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yI0dL0/4)

`(?<=[.]\d{2})` is a positive lookbehind that matches a dot `[.]` followed by two digits `\d{2}`.

Comment: @St.Antario: Looks OK, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using java and the given pattern is `\d\d\.\d\d\w*` you will get `some_text` from `12.34some_text`by using

```
String s="12.34some_text";
s.substring(5,s.length());
```

and you can compare the substring!